# Fedora 28 - Boot stalls for approximately 15 mins before loading into desktop

Tags: fedora, boot

I have been using Fedora since around version 25 on the same computer without any major problems.

I am currently running version 28 (fresh install). However, after running updates through dnf it will start to freeze at a certain point in the boot process for literally 15 mins, and then it will load the desktop. Everything from that point on works perfectly (until the next reboot).

This picture shows what the screen looks like for the 15mins:

[image]

I can see that there is a big red `FAILED` regarding Kernel Modules, and also that it is complaining about ACPI Bios. However, I have no clue where to begin with this, and I can't find any guidance online.

Please also note that if I reinstalled Fedora 28 this would not happen until I run updates. Fedora 27 doesn't have this problem at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as waiting 15 mins on every boot is a little frustrating!

**Update**

This is the output `journalctl -b -perr`:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-07-28 20:25:08 EEST, end at Sat 2018-08-18 18:23:19 EEST. --
Aug 18 21:02:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
Aug 18 21:02:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
Aug 18 21:02:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
Aug 18 21:02:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
Aug 18 21:02:22 localhost.localdomain systemd-modules-load[264]: Failed to find module 'vboxdrv'
Aug 18 21:02:22 localhost.localdomain systemd-modules-load[264]: Failed to find module 'vboxnetflt'
Aug 18 21:02:22 localhost.localdomain systemd-modules-load[264]: Failed to find module 'vboxnetadp'
Aug 18 21:02:22 localhost.localdomain systemd-modules-load[264]: Failed to find module 'vboxpci'
Aug 18 18:02:40 localhost.localdomain systemd-udevd[1011]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sdc1, 10) failed: No such file or directory
Aug 18 18:02:40 localhost.localdomain systemd-udevd[1007]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sdd1, 10) failed: No such file or directory
Aug 18 18:02:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[1694]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
Aug 18 18:07:46 localhost.localdomain sudo[1883]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Aug 18 18:07:46 localhost.localdomain sudo[1883]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [testspecimen]
Aug 18 18:12:48 localhost.localdomain sudo[1973]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Aug 18 18:12:48 localhost.localdomain sudo[1973]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [testspecimen]
Aug 18 18:12:52 localhost.localdomain spice-vdagent[2251]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Aug 18 18:22:19 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1327]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
```

---

**Update**

This is now solved. Turns out I'm at fault which is why it was so difficult to trace. **Never ever** add any lines to `.bash-profile` that contain `sudo`!

Painful lesson learned, and many hours wasted.

Comment: After a successful boot, what do you get with `journalctl -b -perr`?

Comment: Change your network interfaces from auto to hotplug

Comment: One of the kernel updates, I think 4.17.11, had a bug which caused that output. It's fixed in 4.17.12. Update again.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will try what mattdm suggested tonight when I get home, and I will have a look at the network interfaces. With regard to the Kernel. I updated last night to 4.17.14 (from memory) and it still persists

Comment: I have now added the result of mattdm's command suggestion in an update to the OP. Is there any chance that the problem is with VirtualBox (I'm assuming that is what vboxdrv etc is?)

Comment: Ah yes. I once added something to `.bash-profile` that contained `sudo`. Machine did not boot at all (or... maybe I should have waited a full 15 minutes!) Had to do recovery and edit the file via terminal (I exactly what I had done!)